# SQL List most popular items

Tags: php, sql

I have a table named `kb_views` and each time an item is viewed it inserts a new row into this table

there is a column named `kb_seq` which is the `sequence` number of the item in a table called `kb`

whats the best way using PHP to select to most popular 10 items?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Show some work...  This appears to be a simple `select count(*), kb_seq group by kb_seq order by count(*) desc limit 10`

Comment: Use group by ..'count(kb_seq) AS count GROUP BY kp_seq ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best way will be the sql query itself, if kb_seq includes the 
count of each element views you can pull the top 10 by using

```
order by `kb_seq`.`count` desc limit 10
```

and your query should look like this:

```
select * from `kb_seq` order by `kb_seq`.`count` desc limit 10
```

if you dont have such table and only one table wich each row is a view you will have to use group

```
select count(*) as `viewed_times`, id FROM `kb_views` group by `viewed_item_id` order by `viewed_times` desc  limit 10
```

Comment: I don't think you quite understood the question. Every time an item is viewed a new row is added. Therefore there wouldn't be any `count` column; this "count" would come from the number of rows.

Comment: as far as i understand there is seperate table which includes this counts

Comment: Remember `count` is a reserved word in MySQL, so your last query will produce a syntax error

Comment: yes I forgot the `` any way i change it to be more clear name count is also to general..

Comment: @Mike `count` isn't a reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - It's a function http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/  --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count - two different animals  ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- You're right. I guess I had the wrong terminology. What I meant is that using `count` as a column name would have to be escaped with backticks since it exists as a function.

Comment: @talsibony `LIMIT` goes after `ORDER BY` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html - Syntax: `SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] ...
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]`

Comment: @Mike Yeah, just in case a noob visits the question/answer and thinks it's a reserved word. The misconception of `date` was passed around for so long as being one also. ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes thank you this was a type error as in the first query I put it at the end..

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit your requirement:

```
SELECT 
    d.* 
FROM 
    kb d,
    (SELECT 
        s.kb_seq, COUNT(*)
    FROM 
         kb s
    INNER JOIN 
        kb_views ct ON ct.kb_seq = s.kb_seq
    GROUP BY 
        s.kb_seq 
    Order by 
        2 DESC LIMIT 10) f
where 
    d.kb_seq = f.kb_seq
```

See results here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ce76/2)